# Adaptive robot gripper options

Tags: ros, hardware, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm currently working on a project picking bottles of different sizes from a shelf. For this purpose, I need an adaptive robot gripper. However, besides Robotiq, I can't find many gripper manufacturers.

Currently, I use the Robotiq Hand-E with custom fingers, but I need to modify the bottles for this work.

What I need:

- Gripper for grasping round and cubic objects (bottles)
- The bottle diameter is usually 50-100mm
- Ideally electric
- controlled via Modbus or I/O
- Payload up to 2-2.5kg

What I have found so far:

- Robotiq 2F-140 adaptive gripper - best solution, very pricey
- Festo Fin-Ray Effect Fingers + electric parallel gripper - relatively cheap, but no electric parallel grippers from Festo

Are there any other options on the market? And is really everyone using pneumatic grippers? I can't see that happening in an office/bar setting.

Thanks,
Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339878/adaptive-robot-gripper-options/) by [machinekoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/33820/machinekoder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2019-12-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-16**:
You may want to post this on a different forum. ROS Answers may not see the best type of audience for this.

**Comment by [machinekoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/33820/machinekoder/) on 2019-12-16**:
It looks like that. However, I already found a gripper that suits my needs, I will answer my own question shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a bit of internet research I found a few additional options:

- ON-Robot RG2 and RG6
- SAKE Robotics Gripper
- Adaptive Fin-Ray-like gripper from Aliexpress (search "adaptive gripper")

In the end, I decided for the SAKE Robotics gripper, since it seems to fit my application very well and the pricing is lower than the ON-Robot and Robotiq solutions. Moreover, the SAKE gripper comes with ROS drivers and simulation models.

I couldn't find suitable electric long-stroke parallel grippers, so I discarded the fin-ray finger option.

---

Originally posted by [machinekoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/33820/machinekoder/) with karma: 69 on 2019-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0